# Peer dependencies for Angular compatible projects?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm, rxjs

Trying to figure out how to declare RxJS as a peer dependency for an Angular 6 project I'm working on.  For example I looked at [angular/flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) and it declares it's RxJS dependency like this:

```
"requiredAngularVersion": ">=6.0.0 <7.0.0",
"dependencies": {
  "rxjs": "^6.0.0"
}
```

Just curious why it's declared like that and not like this:

```
"requiredAngularVersion": ">=6.0.0 <7.0.0",
"peerDependencies": {
  "rxjs": "^6.0.0"
}
```

### Side Note

Noticed that some projects are matching their major semver version to Angular's Major version.  So for example I'll be using major version 6 for the [@fireflysemantics/slice](https://github.com/fireflysemantics/slice) in order to match it up with Angular 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Just curious why it's declared like that and not like this:

It should be a `peerDependency`. They probably don't want to force people to use `6.0.x` which is what `dependencies` does.

Comment: Super thanks!  Do you know if the `"requiredAngularVersion": ">=6.0.0 <7.0.0",` is something that is used by Angular, or is it just additional meta data?

Comment: Not used by anything else at the moment : https://www.google.com.au/search?sa=X&nfpr=1&q=%22requiredangularversion%22+package.json

Comment: No docs on it yet : https://github.com/angular/material2/commit/a2c6dfc92f0e2fb1028aa40a65054f21a39984db